# Bootstrap 3.2 Toolbar with gaps in it ugly radio buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HI I am trying to draw a list of radio button using bootstrap 3.2, I have enclosed by buttons in a toolbar,  I assumed this would draw the buttons next to each othe, with no gaps between the buttons.

Instead it draws a line of buttons with rounded edges with a gap between each button

My bowser is "Version 39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)", so I assume that I have a modern layout engine. I  assumed this would work 'out of the box'

There is a reference in my code to bootstrap.css

Have I missed something ?

Code is

```
<div class='btn-toolbar' role='toolbar' aria-label='...'>
<h2>Buttons</h2>
<div id='btn-group btn-group-justified' role='group' data-toggle='buttons' aria-label='...'>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type='radio' id='layer1Button' autocomplete='off' name='options' >Fee
</label>
<label class='btn  btn-primary'>
<input type='radio' id='layer2Button' autocomplete='off' name='options' >Fie
</label>
<label class='btn  btn-primary'>
<input type='radio' id='layer3Button' autocomplete='off' name='options' >Foe
</label>
<label class='btn  btn-primary'>
<input type='radio' id='layer4Button' autocomplete='off' name='options' >Foo
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer before. Just realized that you have used `btn-group btn-group-justified` as id and not class. Change that to `class="btn-group btn-group-justified"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp79ovjc/)

```
<h2>Buttons</h2>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" id="layer1Button" autocomplete="off" name="options" > Fee
</label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" id="layer2Button"  autocomplete="off" name="options"  >Fie
</label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" id="layer3Button"  autocomplete="off" name="options"  >Foe
</label>
<label class="btn  btn-primary">
<input type="radio" id="layer4Button"  autocomplete="off" name="options"  >Foo
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, such a simple mistake to make! Thanks @Macsupport